# Tracing Image in android

Tags: java, android, api, image-processing

I want to build an android application similar to
[Write ( ABC abc 123 )](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.threerhinos.learnabcpro)

So is there any API available to perform image tracing or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking for built-in API, the closest I know is [Gestures](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/package-summary.html).